# Getting accurate time measurement with `perf-stat`

Tags: linux-kernel, benchmarking, scheduler, perf

I try to benchmark simple "hello, world" programs written in several languages. I am n00b in this field, and the `perf-stat` manual is not making it easy to accomplish by lack of examples.

To do that I run `perf-stat` at high priority to avoid context switching. So I come up with something like that:

```sh
sudo chrt -f 99 perf stat -e cs -e cpu-clock ./hello_c
```

However, the results I get for the same program differ significantly. For instance the result for the same C compiled executable can be:

```sh
     0      cs                        #    0.000 K/sec                  
  0.42 msec cpu-clock                 #    0.612 CPUs utilized          

0.000694107 seconds time elapsed
0.000713000 seconds user
0.000000000 seconds sys
```

or

```sh
     0      cs                        #    0.000 K/sec                  
  0.58 msec cpu-clock                 #    0.620 CPUs utilized          

0.000936635 seconds time elapsed
0.000000000 seconds user
0.000940000 seconds sys
```

I this particular example there is `0.242528 msec` of incompatibility even when context switches are in both examples equal `0`.

Is there something I am missing, some calculation I need to do? Or it is not possible to get any closer results? Are there any other options to fix this problem then getting average of n executions?

Comment: Have you tried running it under `strace`?  Even the simplest dynamically linked executable makes a bunch of system calls, so there's a lot going on which might hit in L3 cache or it might not.  Plus, CPU frequency isn't constant and could ramp up near the start or near the end of that.  And if you're making a `write` system call to a terminal, you introduce a huge amount of noise by waking up the X server, and your terminal emulator.

Comment: Time a static executable that makes no system calls other than `sys_exit` and runs a microbenchmark loop for at least a few 10s of milliseconds if you want consistent timing.

Comment: Is there a way I can set consistent CPU speed? So you mean I shall write an microbenchmark which repeats the scheduler to get average (I don't really understand your last answer)?

Comment: Disable Turbo and set governor = performance.  The details depend on the specific CPU, e.g. for Intel it depends on whether you're using hardware P-states or not.  On dual/quad-core Intel chips, you can run an infinite loop (ideally containing a `pause` instruction to save power) on another core because all cores share the same clock.  You'll still have some variability due to interrupts and cache misses or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a variety of reasons you can see variation when you repeatedly benchmark what appears to be the same code. I have covered some of the reasons in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49202633/149138) and it would be worthwhile to keep those in mind.

However, based on experience and playing the probabilities, we can eliminate many of those up front. What's left are the most likely causes of your relatively large deviations for short programs from a cold start:

1. CPU power saving and frequency scaling features.
2. Actual runtime behavior differences, i.e., different code executed in the runtime library, VM, OS or other supporting infrastructure each time your run your program.
3. Some caching effect, or code or data alignment effect that varies from run to run.

You can probably separate these three effects with a plain `perf stat` without overriding the event list, like:

```
$ perf stat true

 Performance counter stats for 'true':

          0.258367      task-clock (msec)         #    0.427 CPUs utilized          
                 0      context-switches          #    0.000 K/sec                  
                 0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
                41      page-faults               #    0.159 M/sec                  
           664,570      cycles                    #    2.572 GHz                    
           486,817      instructions              #    0.73  insn per cycle         
            92,503      branches                  #  358.029 M/sec                  
             3,978      branch-misses             #    4.30% of all branches        

       0.000605076 seconds time elapsed
```

Look first at the `2.572 GHz` line. This shows the effective CPU frequency, calculating by dividing the true number of CPU cycles by the `task-clock` value (CPU time spent by the program). If this varies from run to run, the wall-clock time performance deviation is partly or completely explained by this change, and the most likely cause is (1) above, i.e., CPU frequency scaling, including both scaling below nominal frequency (power saving), and above (turbo boost or similar features).

The details of disabling frequency scaling depends on the hardware, but a common one that works on most modern Linux distributions is `cpupower -c all frequency-set -g performance` to inhibit below-nominal scaling.

Disabling turbo boost is more complicated and may depend on the hardware platform and even the specific CPU, but for recent x86 some options include:

- Writing `0` to `/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo` (Intel only)
- Doing a `wrmsr -p${core} 0x1a0 0x4000850089` for each `${core}` in your system (although one on each socket is probably enough on some/most/all chips?). (Intel only)
- Adjust the `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq` value to set a maximum frequency.
- Use the `userspace` governor and `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed` to set a fixed frequency.

Another option is to simply run your test repeatedly, and hope that the CPU quickly reaches a steady state. `perf stat` has built-in support for that with the `--repeat=N` option:

```
   -r, --repeat=<n>
       repeat command and print average + stddev (max: 100). 0 means forever.
```

Let's say you observe that the frequency is always the same (within 1% or so), or you have fixed the frequency issues but some variance remains.

Next, check the `instructions` line. This is a rough indicator of how much total work your program is doing. If it varies in the same direction and similar relative variance to your runtime variance, you have a problem of type (2): some runs are doing more work than others. Without knowing what your program is, it would be hard to say more, but you can use tools like `strace`, `perf record + perf annotate` to track that down.

If `instructions` doesn't vary, and frequency is fixed, but runtime varies, you have a problem of type (3) or "other". You'll want to look at more performance counters to see which correlate with the slower runs: are you having more cache misses? More context switches? More branch mispredictions? The list goes on. Once you find out what is slowing you down, you can try to isolate the code that is causing it. You can also go the other direction: using traditional profiling to determine what part of the code slows down on the slow runs.

Good luck!

Comment: This question isn't tagged `[x86]`, but other than the details of how to pin the CPU frequency on x86, this answer does apply across architectures.

Comment: @PeterCordes - you are right, it is not clear what platform the user is on, I'll rework it to not make the x86 assumption.