# How to correctly measure IPC (Instructions per cycle) with perf

Tags: x86, performancecounter, perf, papi

I wonder how to measure instructions per cycle correctly using perf. As reference: http://www2.engr.arizona.edu/~tosiron/papers/SPEC2017_ISPASS18.pdf used `inst_retired.any` and `cpu_clk_unhalted.ref_tsc` for their calculations, and I'm now wondering if this is the correct approach. In comparison, PAPI uses the hardware counters `PAPI_TOT_INS` and `PAPI_TOT_CYC` to calculate the IPC.

After some measurements I concluded:

- `inst_retired.any:u` seems to be the same as `PAPI_TOT_INS`
- `cpu-cycles` seems to be the same as `PAPI_TOT_CYC`

On an example benchmark, `cpu-cycles` differs from `cpu_clk_unhalted.ref_tsc` by about 25%. The question is now, which of both values is the correct one for calculations?  Or are both approaches wrong?

Comment: We could give a better answer if you provide specific information about the application, system, and system configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cpu-cycles` is the actual core clock frequency which changes with turbo / power-save P-states.  Use it if you care about microarchitectural things like how close to the 4 uops per clock front-end bottleneck you're achieving.

`cpu_clk_unhalted.ref_tsc` is reference cycles, and always ticks at (close to) the rated / sticker speed of the CPU.  (e.g. a fixed 4008 MHz on my 4GHz i7-6700k).  Use it (or `task-clock`) if you care about work per time including the choice to turbo high or to stay at low clock speed when partly memory-bound.  (Depends on EPP energy-performance-preference settings.)

Fun fact: it uses the same clock source as RDTSC, but the event counter doesn't tick when the clock is halted, e.g. during CPU frequency transitions).  [Lost Cycles on Intel? An inconsistency between rdtsc and CPU_CLK_UNHALTED.REF_TSC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45472147/lost-cycles-on-intel-an-inconsistency-between-rdtsc-and-cpu-clk-unhalted-ref-ts)

(Semi-related: [How to get the CPU cycle count in x86_64 from C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772567/get-cpu-cycle-count/51907627#51907627) for more about TSC and `rdtsc`)